# Dynamic fields in New Email ticket OTRS 5

Tags: javascript, otrs

We use agents to create a New Email Ticket after a call or email to us. We do not let a client create an ticket by sending an email.
The agent can enter or choose values on some dynamic fields in OTRS when creating a new ticket.

He can also do this after a ticket is created using Outbound Email.
In the Outbound Email the receiver gets, these Dynamic Fields can be added and this works.

In the email a receiver(client) gets after creating a New Email Ticket, these Dynamic Fields values are not added. This for me is a strange thing because the fields contains important things.

Everything else you type in any text field is added to the email except for these Dynamic Fields.
It seems OTRS is out of the box not able to do this.

It seems there is some Javascript needed for this, but I do not know Javascript.

Does anyone know how to get these Dynamic Fields values into the First email a receiver gets?

Or does anyone have a Javascript which works and is adaptable or can be added to a file of OTRS?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Use OTRS Notification Tags for data to be send in the notifications,
eg:  `<OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_TestField>`

Answer (score 0):

@Crons is right, you can add special tags to you Email-Templates. These tags are listed in the Template editor at the bottom of the page. Unfortunately they are only mentioned in the [admin manual](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/administration.html#adminarea-salutations-signatures-attachments-and-answers) in a single sentence.

> The different variables you can use in templates are listed in the
>   lower part of the salutation screen. If you use, for example, the
>   variable  the last name of the ticket's sender will be
>   included in your reply.

Here's a list of them:

```
<OTRS_OWNER_*>
    Ticket owner options (e. g. <OTRS_OWNER_UserFirstname>). 
<OTRS_RESPONSIBLE_*>
    Ticket responsible options (e. g. <OTRS_RESPONSIBLE_UserFirstname>). 
<OTRS_CURRENT_*>
    Options of the current user who requested this action (e. g. <OTRS_CURRENT_UserFirstname>). 
<OTRS_TICKET_*>
    Options of the ticket data (e. g. <OTRS_TICKET_TicketNumber>, <OTRS_TICKET_TicketID>, <OTRS_TICKET_Queue>, <OTRS_TICKET_State>). 
<OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_*>
    Options of ticket dynamic fields internal key values ( e. g. <OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_TestField>, <OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_TicketFreeText1>). 
<OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_*_Value>
    Options of ticket dynamic fields display values, useful for Dropdown and Multiselect fields ( e. g. <OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_TestField_Value>, <OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_TicketFreeText1_Value>). 
<OTRS_CUSTOMER_DATA_*>
    Options of the current customer user data (e. g. <OTRS_CUSTOMER_DATA_UserFirstname>). 
<OTRS_CONFIG_*>
    Config options (e. g. <OTRS_CONFIG_HttpType>). 

Note: Create type templates only supports this smart tags: <OTRS_CURRENT_*> and <OTRS_CONFIG_*>
```

I just copied the list from the OTRS Interface.

Comment: Yes i know, but these are only valid after the ticket is created. Not when an Email ticket is created. So in the first email the customer is getting after an agent creates a new ticket the values are not being displayed. But are in notifications/boundEmail after that. I have had some help to get the values of dropdowns in the first email, but not yet the free to fill in single line fields. This probably can be solved by a PlaceHolder and let a piece of javascript react on that and get the dynamicfield_this_value an d put it there. Changes are made with a wrapper in AgentTicketEmail.tt